# How to Google form RegEx validation that matches with the "OR" expression in two patterns

Tags: regex, google-forms

I wanted to validate vehicle registration numbers in Sri Lanka in google form.
Here, the registration number is divided into two parts by a `"-"` sign.
The part to the left of the `"-"` sign.
Two or three digits. Or two or three English letters. Numbers and letters are never mixed.

The part to the right of the `"-"` sign.
Always 4 digits.

Below are some example cases.
`12-1234`, `123-1234`, `AB-1234`, `ABC-1234`

The following was the most successful regular expression I tried in google form. But here the numbers and letters are mixed in the left part. `"|"` Sign not working in google form.

```
[0-9A-Za-z]{2}?[0-9A-Za-z]?\-[0-9]{4}
```

Below are the other expressions I tried. None of them succeeded properly.

1. `([0-9A-Za-z]{2})$(?[0-9A-Za-z]?)$\-[0-9]{4}`
2. `^[0-9]{2,3}$|^[A-Za-z]{2,3}$\-[0-9]{4}`
3. `[0-9]{2}?[0-9]?-[0-9]{4}`
4. `[0-9A-Za-z]{2}?[0-9A-Za-z]?\-[0-9]{4}`
5. `[0-9]{2,3}-[0-9]{4}||[a-zA-Z]{2,3}-[0-9]{4}`
6. `[0-9]{2,3}-[0-9]{4}|[a-zA-Z]{2,3}-[0-9]{4}`
7. `[a-zA-Z]{2}?[a-zA-Z]?[0-9]{2}?[0-9]?\-[0-9]{4}`
8. `^([a-zA-Z]{2,3}\-[0-9]{4})$`
9. `^([0-9]{2,3}\-[0-9]{4})$`

can you help me

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you don't want to allow numbers and letters mixed, you will have to use OR and hence you can use following regex,

```
^(?:\d{2,3}|[a-zA-Z]{2,3})-\d{4}$
```

[Check this out](https://regex101.com/r/VhYY0m/1)

Here, `(?:\d{2,3}|[a-zA-Z]{2,3})` allows either 2 to 3 digits or 2 to 3 letters and rest regex is trivial you already know that part.